# What does s.strip() do exactly?

Tags: python

I was told it deletes whitespace but

```
s = "ss asdas vsadsafas asfasasgas"

print(s.strip())
```

prints out

```
ss asdas vsadsafas asfasasgas
```

shouldn't it be `ssasdasvsadsafasasfasasgas`?

Comment: Sorry for stupid question, I am really beginner so could anyone please answer how strip works, I am massively confused.

Answer (score 13):

You should perhaps check out the docs for the function. It trims leading and trailing whitespace.
`" ss ss     ".strip()` becomes `"ss ss"`

Relevant link: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip

Additionally, there is a very powerful tool within the Python interactive interpreter - you can do something like `help("".strip)` to get a bevy of useful information.

Comment: Why is this necessary again?? How can delete whitespace in the middle, if I wanted to.

Comment: @EricJung `s = s.replace(" ", "")`

Answer (score 3):

Definition from [Python's reference](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

```
str.strip([chars])
```

*Return a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters removed*. The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed. If omitted or None, the chars argument defaults to removing whitespace. The chars argument is not a prefix or suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped:

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, `strip()` removes leading and trailing spaces only.

You are looking for `s.replace(" ","")`

Answer (score 2):

#### As we know

```
s.strip()
```

function returns a string in which leading and trailing **spaces** are removed or striped

but if we use strip() function with a argument like-

```
 s="your string goes here"
s.strip("string")
```

now as we have passed the argument as "string" this will be treated as
a set of char **{s,t,r,i,n,g}**
now similarly: as s.strip() strips the leading and trailing spaces 
s.strip("string") will search all the char of the set one by one form left and right side of the string s.

If a char in the string **s** isn't in the set than no further checking is done form that side, searching will be continue from the other side till similar thing is happen form that side. if char in string s is found in set than that char is removed, for example-

**consider the string  :** 
s="this is tricky"

**s.strip("ric")**
now for this our set will be {"r","i","c"}.

Now checking from **left side of string s** first char is "t", since "t" isn't in our set, we stop here.

Now checking from **right side of string s** first char is "y", since "y" isn't in our set , we stop here
**output: "this is tricky"

**s.strip("ingy")**
set={"i","n","g","y"}
only for right side case y is found and removed after that g isn't found so we stop here
**output: "this is trick"

**s.strip("the")**
set={"t","h","e"}
for right side "y" isn't in our set so we stop ,
for left side "t" is present in our set we remove this, check for "h"-present-so remve "h", than "i" not present stop here

**output: "is is tricky"**

Answer (score 1):

Other than deleting leading and trailing whitespaces it strips the passing parameter also.

Like the following:
**string = 'shiv is awesome'**

**print(string.strip('sh'))**

This will print **"iv is awesome"**

But it will become very confusing to strip character like this because it leads to various results like look at the following example.

> s = **"paandroid is awesomean papapa"**
>
> doing **s.strip('p')** will do **nothing**
>
> If you give  s = **"paapandroid is awesomean papa"**
>
> doing **s.strip('pa')** here it gives **'ndroid is awesomean '** with a space in last. What it means that it is recursively deleting any such **pa** containing one or more each character on suffixes and prefixes of the string.
>   See some more results by doing strip on **"paapandroid is awesomean papa"**.